# Is it possible to hide row numbers in a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

When looking at a numbered list that starts at the number 1, the row numbers are potentially confusing. (Assuming one has row 1 as column heading labels, `item 1` will be on row 2, `item 2` on row 3, and so on.)

Is there a way to turn off row and column headings, as there is in most spreadsheet programs?

In case I'm not making sense, the picture below should clear things up:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not possible. This sounds like a good feature request for Google Docs.

Answer (score 3):

I added a blank column before my numbers and made my numbers **BOLD** so that my eyes are drawn there and not to the default google sheet numbers.

Answer (score 2):

On the Google Sheets spreadsheet view is not possible.

One alternative is to publish to the web.  It's worth to note that headers parameter could be used used to  show/hide the headers. Use `headers=true` to show and `headers=false` to hide, if omitted the headers are hidden.

Example:

(The unique file id was replaced by `...`)

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/.../pubhtml?headers=false`

**References**

From the Google Docs Editors Official Help Forum

- [Answer](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12966494?hl=en&msgid=12970942) by [GregE](https://support.google.com/profile/640586), Google Product Expert to [How to remove column and row headers (with numbers) as we can do it in excel ?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/12966494?hl=en) (2019)

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Publish to the Web, then under "Get a link to the published data" select "Web page", then the sheet you wish to publish.  Then select the cells you wish to show.  Then copy the generated link.

You may have to play with the sharing options (ie anyone with the link can edit).

Comment: That's a good suggestion....but perhaps needs a bit more facts. Can you show us a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's too bad Google aren't implementing this. I just put together a little JavaScript bookmarklet for this purpose [here](https://gist.github.com/lmmx/184734b209f3b5c935c9#file-bookmarklet). Clicking once inserts a CSS style to hide the headers, clicking again removes the CSS and shows them again.

> `javascript:(function(){var hidecss = "body { margin-left: -45px;`
>   `margin-top: -47px; } div.grid-table-container { width: 100%`
>   `!important; }`
>   `div.native-scrollbar.native-scrollbar-ltr.native-scrollbar-y { left:`
>   `initial !important; right: 0px; }`
>   `div.goog-inline-block.grid4-inner-container { width: 100% !important;`
>   `}"; if (document.querySelector('#hidecss')===null){ var hidescript =`
>   `document.createElement('style'); hidescript.type = 'text/css';`
>   `hidescript.id = 'hidecss'; hidescript.innerHTML = hidecss;`
>   `document.head.appendChild(hidescript); } else`
>   `document.getElementById('hidecss').remove();})();`

May have to be tuned to other screen sizes but that's the gist of it !

**Edit** formatted JS:

```
var hidecss = "body { margin-left: -45px; margin-top: -47px; } div.grid-table-container { width: 100% !important; } div.native-scrollbar.native-scrollbar-ltr.native-scrollbar-y { left: initial !important; right: 0px; } div.goog-inline-block.grid4-inner-container { width: 100% !important; }";
if (document.querySelector('#hidecss')===null){
    var hidescript = document.createElement('style');
    hidescript.type = 'text/css';
    hidescript.id = 'hidecss';
    hidescript.innerHTML = hidecss;
    document.head.appendChild(hidescript);
}
else document.getElementById('hidecss').remove();
```

It's an ugly hack since Google doesn't make webapps that play well with user modification like this, so it's only visual (trying to click on cells brings you to different cells and the highlighting is messed up). I ended up not using it

Comment: Can you please reformat your code so that it is code (each line preceded by 4 spaces) rather than using backticks and blockquotes. I'd do it myself, but I can't work out where the linebreaks should go.

Comment: I just posted the bookmarklet code... the formatted CSS and JS is at the link if you want to see that

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible (I think). But there is another method you could use to make it less confusing. Make the numbers that you use (The ones that you use for Volume) and make it stand out more. Such as making it bigger, bolding it, or changing it's color to a red (Since Red get's a person's attention more and why youtuber color is red, to stand out more.) I know this is old but for anyone looking for an answer, you may use mind.